# how can i read a text in pdf in reference to other text with Selenium

Tags: selenium

How can i read a particular text in a pdf file with reference to some other text in selenium.

Total Monthly Service Charge   $289.30

For instance, i have this above text, I would like to extract the Total Monthly Service Charge amount from the PDF, how can I do that using Selenium WebDriver

Note: I am aware of PDFTextStripper class

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is not a debugging question. I need to know if there is any way we can achieve it.

Comment: could this be because I am using log4j ?